# Keras: Converting Seq model to Functional API

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently trying to scale up a time series example I found in a book. I have been trying to move it to the functional API but I'm having problems. The error I'm experienced in the functional model is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "merge_n.py", line 57, in
>   
>       lstm = LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True)(inputs)   File
>   "/Users/pjhampton/Desktop/MTL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py",
>   line 243, in **call**
>       return super(Recurrent, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)   File "/Users/pjhampton/Desktop/MTL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 541, in **call**
>       self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)   File "/Users/pjhampton/Desktop/MTL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 440, in assert_input_compatibility
>       str(K.ndim(x))) ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

**Sequential Model (original)**

```
########################################################
# main input
########################################################
look_back = 5
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1)) 
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))

batch_size = 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True)) 
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

for i in range(100):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

**Functional API based model (What I've tried)**

```
inputs = Input(shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1))

lstm = LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True)(inputs)
dense = Dense(1)(lstm)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
for i in range(100):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

Full code: https://friendpaste.com/3Zg3VKBs3qd7FNXubNONzN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified that your RNN is stateful, therefore you need to specify the `batch_shape` in the input.

```
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1))

lstm = LSTM(4, stateful=True)(inputs)
dense = Dense(1)(lstm)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
for i in range(100):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

It seems that the sequential model is exactly what you are looking for though.